# How to ignore error from path in Typescript (exclude doesn't work)?

Tags: typescript

example:

```
require('some-module-I-dont-own")
```

error:

```
> tsc
node_modules/some-module-I-dont-own/types/lib/index.d.ts:1:1 - error TS1110: Type expected.
1   method: string | [string, ...unknown[]];
```

I don't own this module. It's not my error. I can't change it. Why can't I just ignore the error? I put `node_modules` in tsconfig exclude but that doesn't help because I'm requiring it.

edit: this is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "lib"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Just put `node_modules` to `exclude` path of tsconfig file.

Comment: @hoangdv how would that help? the module is being required, so exclude does nothing

Comment: @user12341234 were you able to fix it?